# String to Unicode in Java

Tags: java, unicode

I have a large string I need to convert all the non alphanumeric chars to unicode

For example

Input string : `abc12/dad-das/das_sdj`

Output String : `abc12:002Fdad:002Ddas:002Fdas:002Fsdj`

Currently I am using this function

```
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.printf(":%04X \n", (int) c);
}
```

Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Can you define better?

Comment: If it's a particularly "large string", you would be better off iterating with a basic for loop `for (int i = 0; i < str.length; ++i)`, and using `str.charAt(i)`; this avoids creating a new `char[]`.

Comment: All the characters already *are* Unicode. It seems that you mean you want to replace them with Unicode *escapes*.

Comment: You're not returning a new string here, really, just printing

Comment: Seems like an XY Problem. What is your larger goal?

Comment: I think you're saying you want to convert the non-alphanumeric characters to their hexadecimal representations in UTF-16.  Right?  Unicode is not an encoding!

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you mean by "non-alphanumeric".  Do you mean not a letter or number as used in English (so not 0-9, A-Z or a-z)?  Or not a letter or number from any language?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I am only expecting ASCII charachters.

Comment: @TomBlodget The goal is to query something on a remote server and this is the way the lookup keys have been encoded at the remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it:

```
// Looping over string characters
private static String convert(String input) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(input.length() + 16);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
            buf.append(c);
        else
            buf.append(String.format(":%04X", (int) c));
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

```
// Using regular expression
private static String convert(String input) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(input.length() + 16);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]").matcher(input);
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(buf, String.format(":%04X", (int) m.group().charAt(0)));
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(convert("abc12/dad-das/das_sdj"));
```

*Output*

```
abc12:002Fdad:002Ddas:002Fdas:005Fsdj
```

Comment: Or instead of  `(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')` we can use `Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)`, assuming OP may want to include also non English characters.

Comment: I wish you had posted this as two separate answers, so that I could upvote the one that I like.

Comment: @Pshemo If you want to encode any non-letter character, including `_` (underscore), it seems fairly certain that accented letters should be encoded too, which is why I quite deliberately steered clear of `isLetterOrDigit()` and `\\w`.